# Define BOOST_PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT has no effect

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

In my grammatic for **boost::Spirit::Q** in semantic action i need many (over 10) attribute placeholders. I try define **BOOST_PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT** variable, as recommended in [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/core/arguments.html), but it had no effect. If anybody know, how make it, say me, please. Version of **boost** is 1.48.0, compiler is **MinGW GCC 4.4.0**.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined the macro in a source file try to pass the macro directly to the compiler command line, maybe it is not visible in all source files.

Comment: Well, [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5c1c6d5b1a71710385db0f0e15882178) is it 'minimal' compiled example of my problem.